# how to show a table based on 2 parameters in report viewer in vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, reporting-services, parameters, reportviewer

i have a report where i need to show a view from my database based on 2 parameters (1 combo box and 1 variable) from a Form.

Here is the image of my View (view_population).
[image: view_population]

Here is the code i used to fill the table for the Reports.

```
 Me.view_populationTableAdapter.Fill(Me.phil_vetDataSet.view_population)
```

I need to filter the view based on the Year (combo box) and the Category (varCategory) from a Form (frmReport) but how do I use the 2 parameters to filter the table of the Report?

I used this code to do it but i don't know how to use it properly.

```
Dim varCategory As String = ""
If frmReport.cbBackyard.Checked = True Then
    varCategory = "Backyard"
ElseIf frmReport.cbCommercial.Checked = True Then
    varCategory = "Commercial"
Else
    varCategory = ""
End If

Dim Year As New ReportParameter("for_year", frmReport.cboYear.Text)
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(Year)
```

I need this output in the Report but i don't know how to put the sql statement in the Form to filter the view.

[image]

Any suggestion and comments are greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to filter report at runtime you can do something like that.

```
Dim con As New OleDbConnection
    con.ConnectionString = connection_string
    con.Open()


    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("<Query>", con)

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)

    da.Fill(ds)

    Dim rpt As New <ReportName>
    rpt.SetDataSource(ds.Tables(0))



    <TableName>.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()
```

This code is just to give you an idea how u will do it. for the parameters you just need to add objects in the query and it will filter the record for you in report.

Comment: I'm using Windows Report Viewer. On your code, `Dim rpt As New <ReportName>` and `<TableName>.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource` I don't know how to use it on my codes. I tried to change it to my report's name. however the error said `ReportSource is not a member of Microsoft.Reporting.Winforms.ReportViewer`. thank you for your idea sir

Comment: Oh, i get it know sir :) Thanks :))

Comment: Glad to help, let me know if you need any more help.